# Convert .patch to html output with styling for online viewing

Tags: php

So I have a tool where users can users upload their SVN `.patch` files. Rather than downloading and viewing it separately I was hoping if it can be viewed directly online with the red green styling.

**The patch file [/uploads/Bug123.patch]**

```
### Eclipse Workspace Patch 1.0
Index: src/main/java/com/admin/Screen.java
===================================================================
--- src/main/java/com/admin/Screen.java (revision 2)
+++ src/main/java/com/admin/Screen.java (working copy)
@@ -147,20 +147,22 @@
-       System.out.println("Hello World"); 
+       System.out.println("Hello New World");
```

**The Viewable [/viewer.php?file=Bug123.patch]**

```
<html><style>.red {background:lightcoral} .green {background:greenyellow} .yellow {background:yellow; font-weight:bold}</style><pre>
### Eclipse Workspace Patch 1.0
Index: src/main/java/com/admin/Screen.java
===================================================================
<span class="yellow">--- src/main/java/com/admin/Screen.java    (revision 2)</span>
<span class="yellow">+++ src/main/java/com/admin/Screen.java    (working copy)</span>
@@ -147,20 +147,22 @@
<span class="red">-     System.out.println("Hello World"); </span>
<span class="green">+       System.out.println("Hello New World"); </span>
</pre></html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @scragar How to do it ? take the patch file as input and output the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something along the lines of this:

```
<?php

$file = __DIR__ . '/foo.patch';

echo '<doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.header {
   color: black;
}
.header-comment {
   color: grey;
}
.file-input, .file-change {
   color: green;
}
.file-output {
   color: blue;
}
.file-line-nos {
   color: blue;
}
.line-context {
   color: darkgrey;
}
.line-add {
   color: green;
}
.line-change {
   color: yellow;
}
.line-del {
   color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
';


echo PatchParser::file_to_html($file);

echo '</body></html>';

class PatchParser {
   const MODE_HEADER = 1;
   const MODE_FILE = 2;

   const LINE_TYPE_HEADER       = 0x0001;
   const LINE_TYPE_COMMENT      = 0x0002;
   const LINE_TYPE_FILE_IN      = 0x1001;
   const LINE_TYPE_FILE_OUT     = 0x1002;
   const LINE_TYPE_FILE_CHANGE  = 0x1003;
   const LINE_TYPE_LINE_NUMBERS = 0x1004;
   const LINE_TYPE_CONTEXT      = 0x2001;
   const LINE_TYPE_ADDITION     = 0x2002;
   const LINE_TYPE_DELETION     = 0x2003;
   const LINE_TYPE_CHANGE       = 0x2004;

   const MARKER_IN_FILE               = '+++';
   const MARKER_CHANGED_FILE          = '***'; // Used for context diffs
   const MARKER_OUT_FILE              = '---';
   const MARKER_FILE_LINE_NUMBERS     = '@';
   const MARKER_HEADER_COMMENT        = '#';
   const MARKER_FILE_CHANGE           = '!';
   const MARKER_FILE_NORMAL_ADDITION  = '>';
   const MARKER_FILE_NORMAL_DELETION  = '<';
   const MARKER_FILE_UNIFIED_ADDITION = '+';
   const MARKER_FILE_UNIFIED_DELETION = '-';


   static public function file_to_html($file){
      return self::text_to_html(file_get_contents($file));
   }

   static public function text_to_html($contents){
      $parsed_lines = self::parse($contents);

      $classes = array(
         self::LINE_TYPE_HEADER        => 'header header-text',
         self::LINE_TYPE_COMMENT       => 'header header-comment',
         self::LINE_TYPE_FILE_IN       => 'file file-input',
         self::LINE_TYPE_FILE_OUT      => 'file file-output',
         self::LINE_TYPE_FILE_CHANGE   => 'file file-change',
         self::LINE_TYPE_LINE_NUMBERS  => 'file file-line-nos',
         self::LINE_TYPE_CONTEXT       => 'line line-context',
         self::LINE_TYPE_ADDITION      => 'line line-add',
         self::LINE_TYPE_DELETION      => 'line line-del',
         self::LINE_TYPE_CHANGE        => 'line line-change'
      );

      $no_lines = count($parsed_lines);
      $lines_width = strlen("$no_lines");

      $output = '<pre>';
      foreach ($parsed_lines AS $line_no => $line){
         ++$line_no;
         $output .= str_pad($line_no, $lines_width, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT)
            . ' '
            . '<span class="'
            . $classes[$line[1]]
            . '">'
            . htmlspecialchars($line[0])
            . '</span><br />';
      }
      return $output . '</pre>';
   }

   static public function parse($contents) {
      $lines = explode("\n", $contents);
      $output = array();

      $mode = self::MODE_HEADER;// Stay's in header mode until we encounter a file handle
      foreach ($lines AS $line) {
         // trim the line to remove excess whitespace, then test the prefix
         $trimmed_line = trim($line);
         $first_three_chars = substr($trimmed_line,0,3);

         // The types that can occur in both modes are the file names/types
         if ($first_three_chars === self::MARKER_IN_FILE) {
            $output[] = array($line, self::LINE_TYPE_FILE_IN);
            $mode = self::MODE_FILE;
            continue;
         }

         if ($first_three_chars === self::MARKER_CHANGED_FILE) {
            $output[] = array($line, self::LINE_TYPE_FILE_CHANGE);
            $mode = self::MODE_FILE;
            continue;
         }

         if (substr($trimmed_line,0,3) === self::MARKER_OUT_FILE) {
            $output[] = array($line, self::LINE_TYPE_FILE_OUT);
            $mode = self::MODE_FILE;
            continue;
         }

         // Otherwise our mode is important:
         if ($mode === self::MODE_HEADER){
            // Header mode only supports header text and comments:
            if (substr($trimmed_line, 0, 1) === self::MARKER_HEADER_COMMENT) {
               $output[] = array($line, self::LINE_TYPE_COMMENT);
            } else {
               $output[] = array($line, self::LINE_TYPE_HEADER);
            }
            continue;
         } else {
            $first_char = substr($line, 0, 1);
            $type = self::LINE_TYPE_CONTEXT;
            switch ($first_char) {
               case self::MARKER_FILE_CHANGE:
                  $type = self::LINE_TYPE_CHANGE;
                  break;
               case self::MARKER_FILE_LINE_NUMBERS:
                  $type = self::LINE_TYPE_LINE_NUMBERS;
                  break;
               case self::MARKER_FILE_NORMAL_ADDITION:
               case self::MARKER_FILE_UNIFIED_ADDITION:
                  $type = self::LINE_TYPE_ADDITION;
                  break;
               case self::MARKER_FILE_NORMAL_DELETION:
               case self::MARKER_FILE_UNIFIED_DELETION:
                  $type = self::LINE_TYPE_DELETION;
                  break;
            }
            $output[] = array($line, $type);
         }
      }
      return $output;
   }
}
```

There's a JS fiddle of the output of what I just posted [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q3weahrr/).

Let me know what you think. It's logic is pretty simple.